# Change of hostName in Terminal to: m:~ myMacUserName$?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I just opened Terminal and I see this `m:~ luka$` and not the default that I usually get of "lukasMacBookProEtcEtc:~ luka$

Anyone know why this is? Does this make an impact on what I write into the command line?

Can't find anything on the elsewhere.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions, and this is a general networking and command-line question, so this should probably be migrated to another Stack Exchange site—probably Super User—or deleted as off-topic.

Comment: Sure, how can we migrate it?

Comment: I've flagged this for migration using the “flag” link, which also counts as a vote to close this.

Comment: Yup, I did the same thing. Great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your computer's host name has changed. This is typical if you switch to a different network, unless you have a statically assigned name or IP address. By default, your computer asks the current network what name to use for itself.

Whether this particular host name is correct or incorrect requires more context. If network operations are working fine for you, then there probably isn't an issue.

No, in general the hostname doesn't directly affect what you write into the command line unless you're writing commands that depend on the current hostname or this unexpected hostname is a symptom of a networking issue and you try entering a command that depends on networking.

Note that on OS X a given computer has at least two different names. One is the “computer name”, typically assigned by the user, and the other is the “host name”, typically assigned to your computer by a server on the local network. The former is the “Computer Name:” at the top of **System Preferences > Sharing**, and users can usually feel free to name their computers as they wish unless otherwise directed by a system administrator. The host name is visible as the output of the `hostname` command and is typically displayed in the shell command prompt. You should normally not attempt to change the host name unless directed to by a system administrator.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah I'm frequently in different locations. It's just strange that the name changed. Can this be done manually or it's purely based on location?

Comment: It is typical that computers dynamically ask a server on the current network to tell them what their name is on the current network. On OS X you can manually edit the name in **System Preferences > Sharing**, but you should not do that unless directed to by a system administrator responsible for assigning your computer a specific name.

Comment: Ok great. In this case, it's my laptop. It won't mess anything up when using the command line, right? (if it's static?) Sorry, I'm a SUPER nube with the command line!

Comment: I can't promise you won't mess up anything when issuing commands—that entirely depends on what commands you're issuing—but the hostname changing when on a different network is typical and doesn't directly indicate that there are any problems or that commands you issue won't work, and, other than the possibility of networking-dependent commands failing to work because of networking issues, the hostname changing when you change networks is not likely to change the outcome of a command that does not depend on which network you're connected to.

Comment: Thank you so much. Wonderful explanation!